# Changing a txt attachment to csv format in coldfusion

Tags: csv, coldfusion, cfmail

I am working with a ColdFusion file which will send a email with an attachment when a user exports data from a system. 
Currently the attachment is in .txt format which is difficult to interpret and is therefore quite unhelpful. I am trying to figure out how I can change this so the attachment sent in the email is in .csv format.
This is the section of code that I believe needs to be altered:

```
    <cfset FileName = "#request.uncPath#\IncidentSummarySystem\data\" & #variable.UserName# & "-" &#DateFormat(now(), "ddmmyyyy")# & "-" & #TimeFormat(now(), "HHmmss")# & ".txt">  <cffile action="Write" file=#FileName# output="#FileData#">
<cfmail to="#rsUsers.qryUserEmail#" from="IncidentSummarySystem@" subject="Incident Summary System Export File" mimeattach="#FileName#">
    DO NOT REPLY TO THIS E-MAIL.
    Incident Summary System:  Your report is attached as a text (.txt) file.
</cfmail>
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.alert ("The information you have requested will be sent to you via e-mail.");
</script>
<cffile action="Delete" file="#FileName#">
```

Is it possible to change the attachment file type to .csv and how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The code where you create this file is relevant, but not included in the question.

Comment: You might want to remove that email address if it's an account that can receive mail.

Comment: FYI, Rolled back changes. S.O. is a [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (Question and Answer) site. If you overwrite the original "question", the subsequent "answers" no longer make sense ;-) Better to *append* changes, as an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25631896/edit), while leaving the original question intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `mimeattach`, use `cfmailparam` to attach the file. If it's a simple CSV file with a `.txt` extension, change it to .csv when you create it. Then, specify the mime-type in the `type` attribute of `cfmailparam` to `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

```
<cfmail 
    to = "recipient"
    subject = "message subject"
    from = "sender"
        more attributes... >
    <cfmailparam 
        contentID = "content ID"
        disposition = "disposition type"
        file = "filename" 
        type ="media type">
    ...
</cfmail>
```

Comment: Hello @Adrian I have made the changes you suggested however I am still getting the attachment sent to me in `.txt` format. I have had to leave out disposition and ContentID as the system did not recognise those attributes.

Comment: This is how my code currently looks: ` <cfmail 
    to = "#rsUsers.qryUserEmail#"
    subject = "Incident Summary System Export File"
    from = "IncidentSummarySystem@schl.co.nz">
    <cfmailparam 
        file = "#FileName#" 
        type ="application/vnd.ms-excel">
  DO NOT REPLY TO THIS E-MAIL.
  Incident Summary System:  Your report is attached as a text (.txt) file.
 </cfmail>` (Apologies for the terrible formatting. I am still getting my head around how to use this site)

Comment: @MichaelBrown - To add additional code, or info, just use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25631896/edit) option :) Then delete the redundant comment.

Comment: Thank You, I just had to replace the .txt sections with .csv and it worked correctly